# round up a number in python

Tags: python, thonny

I would like to know how do we round up a number on python without using the math.ceil function. I have tried to use a condition "if" but it doesn't work.
for example : 4.01 would become 5 and 4.0 would stay 4. How do we do that please ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you show your relevant code? Whatever you have done so far and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: `round(x + 0.5)` or `x//1 + (x%1 > 0)`

Comment: There's plenty of answers in the linked duplicate that don't use `math.ceil`

Answer (score 4):

```
round(x + 0.5)
```

Check that this works for 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc to make sure that .5 always rounds down.

If not, convert to an Int and if the original is greater, add one.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a function to do this

```
def ceil(f): 
  return int(f) + (1 if f-int(f) else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using the `round()` function:

```py
a =2.22
round(a) # 2

b = 5.89
round(b) # 6
```

Comment: OP wants the number to be rounded always up, while your example clearly shows normal rounding

Comment: You can also enter a second argument to choose how many decimals, like round(2.22,1) = 2.2

Comment: @Felipe this is still not what OP asked for...

Comment: @Filipe you are right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the number is a integer if the x%int(x) == 0. If it is, do do nothing, else, return the integer plus 1:

```
rd = lambda x: int(x) if x%int(x) == 0 else int(x) + 1
#rd(4.1) = 5
#rd(4) = 4
```